# Deploy a library via GPO

Tags: group-policy

I have a Carbon folder in "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Carbon" in my AD Server 
How do I deploy this folder (and its content) to same location ("C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules") in the endpoints of the domain via GPO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepare a ps1 scritp:

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\R10.Local\SYSVOL\R10.local\Carbon" -Destination "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" -Recurse -Force
```

then I did as follow:

DC: Copy the Carbon folder to \{domain name}\SYSVOL\R10.local\ path 
 DC: DC: Create a new Policy (Group Policy Object named Carbon) in DC > GPO 
 GPO: go to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts > Startup > PowerShell Scripts 
 GPO: click Show File and drag the CopyCarbon.ps1 to that location 
 GPO: edit the Security of the file and add DOMAIN Computers group with Read, Read & Execute permission 
 GPO: PowerShell Scripts: Add the RabbitMQTools file to PowerShell Scripts tab 
 GPO: PowerShell Scripts: Validate that the ps1 file is loaded to Sysvol share folder by clicking on Show File button (e.g. \{domain name}\SysVol\R10.local\Policies{GUID}\Machine\Scripts\Startup) 
 GPO: PowerShell Scripts: select the file and click on Edit 
 (Optional) GPO: PowerShell Scripts: paste the following parameters:
`-Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –Noprofile -file`